# Comments in app are hard to distinguish from title

Tags: feature-request, android-app, global-inbox, information-display

In the Android app, the comments show up on the right side when I swipe to the left.  Each comment shows up with the title of the question and then the content of the comment.  The problem is that it is hard to distinguish between them.

[image: screenshot]

Can there be a color change or addition of bold to make it easier to see what is in the comment and what is in the title?

Comment: I've closed this as no longer reproducible because the mobile apps have been discontinued for years now, and are no longer supported.